# does the MySQL Connector/Python work with python 3.6.1

Tags: mysql, python-3.6, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to use Python to interact with a MySQL database using the python connector found on the MySQL website `mysql-connector-python-2.1.3-py3.4-winx64`. In the MySQL Connector Manual it says that it should work with a anything above python 3.3, Here is a link to that manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html

Running the connector program appears to work fine, but when I attempt to `import mysql.connector` the module not found error occurred. I had previously installed python 3.4 and the import worked perfectly fine, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

No, mysql-connector does not support 3.6 on Windows, it seems. When I tried to install the connector program with 3.6 installed (this morning, 11 Jan 2018), the connector installer prompted me that it could not find 3.4.

I've had no problems using connector on Mac.